# Crop taken screenshot and save image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using this code to take a screenshot of my specific UIView which is inside in my main view.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_myView.frame.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *imageSave = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Main view size is (0,0,320,480) lets say, and myView size is (10,20,200,150)

Now i would like to capture/take a screenshot only of myView.

The above code doesn't capture exactly how i want, any suggestions?

Comment: How does it capture, and how does that compare to exactly what you want?

Comment: @nhgrif its not exactly like myView, its larger including some areas from main view, includes the top of main view also, even myView starts with 10,20.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
- (UIImage *)snapshotOfView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);

    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return viewImage;
}
```